# Stuck parallelisation with sklearn with large number of features (n_jobs=-1)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scikit-learn

When trying to run a simple `GridSearchCV` with `n_job=-1` often results in stuck processing. For example,

```
>> parameters_SGD = {'clf__l1_ratio': np.linspace(0,1,30), 'clf__alpha': np.logspace(-5,-1,5), 'clf__penalty':['elasticnet'], 'clf__class_weight': [None, 'balanced'],'clf__loss':['log','hinge']}
>> pipe_SGD = Pipeline([('scl', StandardScaler()),('clf', linear_model.SGDClassifier())])
>> grid_search_SGD = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe_SGD, param_grid=parameters_SGD, verbose=1, scoring=make_scorer(f1_score, average='weighted', pos_label=1), n_jobs = -1)
```

executing on some data (X_train, y_train):

```
>> grid_search_SGD.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

may result in frozen computations -> CPU usage drops to 1-3% and nothing happens.

**When it happens:** if the number of features of `X` is (relatively) large (>100). The CPU usage climbs up to 99% (which means all cores work) and then suddenly drops down to 1-3%.

If I use only small subset of features (randomly selected), then parallelisation works perfectly (99-100% of CPU and I can see jobs done in parallel).

**Does anyone have any idea why it happens?** What may cause parallel jobs to be stuck?

(sklearn v 0.18, mac osx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Reason

Parallelization in this case is based on copying all the data and send a copy to each of the different parallel processes (sklearn is based on [joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html)). This means using `X cores` needs at least `x-times` the memory of the naive one.

So in your case your memory probably is exhausted and [trashing occurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)).

## What you can do

### Stick with smaller size of samples / less features

You already observed that this works

### Tune sklearn's GridSearchCV params

As explained [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), the parameter `pre_dispatch` can be very important:

> Controls the number of jobs that get dispatched during parallel execution. Reducing this number can be useful to avoid an explosion of memory consumption when more jobs get dispatched than CPUs can process. This parameter can be:
>   None, in which case all the jobs are immediately created and spawned. Use this for lightweight and fast-running jobs, to avoid delays due to on-demand spawning of the jobs
>   An int, giving the exact number of total jobs that are spawned
>   A string, giving an expression as a function of n_jobs, as in ‘2*n_jobs’

I would recommend trying something like:

```
pre_dispatch=‘1*n_jobs’
```

(A sidenote: without any links available, i'm very positive that OS X is the OS with the most problems in regards to sklearn's parallelization-implementation; maybe check the issues on sklearn's github)

Comment: amazing! I experimented with the size of my `X` matrix (both, number of rows and columns) and the `freezing` problem is indeed occurs when the size becomes larger than some threshold. So it is memory trashing. If you have any other tips on mitigating this problem, please suggest.

Comment: I think you mean "thrashing", not "trashing".